# Eigenvalues calculations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am going calculate the eigenvalues follow program:
I want to calculate the matrix H , and achieve eigenvalues.

```
acc=1.44e-10;
a=1.732*acc;
t=-2.550;
x1=0;
y1=0;
z1=0;
x2=acc*cos(60);
y2=acc*sin(60);
z2=0;
sh=0; 

for i=-1:1
    for j=-1:1
        for k=1:2
            sh=sh+1;
            xk=acc*cos(60)*(k-1);
            yk=acc*sin(60)*(k-1);
            zk=0;
            xx(sh)=(i*a)+(j*a/2)+xk;
            yy(sh)=(sqrt(3)/2)*a*j+yk;
            zz(sh)=zk;
            ki(sh)=k;
            R1(sh)=i;
            R2(sh)=j;
        end
    end
end

L0=sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2);

r1=0:0.02:1;
kx=(2*pi/(sqrt(3)*a))*(1-r1);
ky=(2*pi/(3*a))*(1-r1);
for ik=1:50
    for i=1:2
        for j=1:sh
            Dis(i+8,j)=sqrt((xx(i)-xx(j))^2+(yy(i)-yy(j))^2+(zz(i)-zz(j))^2);
            if abs(Dis-L0)<0.1
                Rx=R1(sh)*a+R2(sh)*a/2;
                Ry=R2(sh)*sqrt(3)/2*a;
                H(ki(i+8),ki(j))=H(ki(i+8),ki(j))+t*exp(1i*(kx(ik)*Rx+ky(ik)*Ry));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But I always get this error:

```
Error in  (line 44)
                H(ki(i+8),ki(j))=H(ki(i+8),ki(j))+t*exp(1i*(kx(ik)*Rx+ky(ik)*Ry));
Undefined function 'H' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Where do you define/initialize `H`? And are `ki` and `ik` are different?

Comment: also you should know that `eig` function in matlab calculates eigenvalues for you.

Comment: ik and ki differents.

Comment: `x2`, `a`, `acc`, `ki` undefined. correct the question please.

Comment: x2, a , acc defined and  ki==ki(sh) . H is the matrix 2*2 as off-diagonal components is H mentioned in program.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize `H` in the beginning, the code works.

```
H = zeros(2,2);
```

**Notice:**

I do not know the way you are calculating the eigenvalues. You should use the predefined function `eig` to check your solution. Another ways is to use `SVD` to calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: in the matrix H : H(2,1)=conj(H(1,2)), How defined H(2,1)??